# How to pass a "?" as a routing parameter in express while using node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, web-development-server

I am creating a blog website for my college using express and nodejs this might be a silly question but I need an answer.
as you can see from the following piece of code-

```
enter code here
cons express = require("express");
.....
.....
app.get("/blog/:title_of_blog", function(request, response){ 
    var title_requested = request.params.title_of_blog;
    console.log(title_requested);
})
```

It works fine in all the cases I tried except when if a user enters a string in as a routing parameter like "what is your name?" then it console logs only "what is your name"

So a question mark gets excluded here on which further process depends as it should be exactly the same,

Is there any way I could fix this???

If you do need any additional information please do let me know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

certain Characters such as  ?, @  are not allowed in URL Parsing or I recently discovered even while storing cookies, but there is a simple way to avoid these problems and get your string in the desired way

```
var encodedString = encodeURI(rawString);
```

this above line turns all the characters such as @ into an easily parsable string and after the string is processed whenever you need the actual string you just have to type one line to get the original string

```
var originalString = decodeURI(enodedString);
```

Answer (score 1):

Because express will understand `?` is for starting a query string. So usually if you want to put blog title to URL, you can parse title to slug using some lib.

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript, PHP, and ASP there are functions that can be used to URL encode a string.

PHP has the rawurlencode() function, and ASP has the Server.URLEncode() function.

In JavaScript you can use the encodeURIComponent() function.

[source](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.ASP)

When you apply encoding on your `blog title` and pass URL Become like this

`/blog/what%20is%20your%20name%20%3F`

You will got the exact result as you want. :)